# nginx CSS break after adding rewrite from $ to $.php

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

If I will add the following line to my nginx configuration it will break my website and will run without CSS:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|xml)$ {
  access_log        off;
  expires           30d;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php =404;
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /$1.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

if I comment the rewrite condition everything will work fine.

What can I do to bring both things to work, the rewrite condition and the css style sheet?

Edit: I got a new problem, now all files like `test.php` work fine without writing `.php`, but folders like `users/` won't work, I still reveive `File not found`, normaly it should take the `index.php` or `index.html` from the folder, how can I provide both functions? add `.php` to files and use `inde.php/html` from folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the try_files and rewrite by replacing the `location /` block with the following two location blocks:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriterules;
}

location @rewriterules { 
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

That way try_files goes first, and if no file is found there is a rewrite and .php is added to the request, which is then executed by the .php location block which should need no modification.

Comment: if I will only add your `try_files` without any `rewrite`, it will work for folders and names with endings, but if I type only `test` I will receive the php file as a download.

Comment: I edited my answer with a different solution to keep the `rewrite`, this should work as expected.

Comment: won't work, still 404, looks like he doesn't fall into the `@rewriterule`

Comment: 404 for what file exactly? Because these location blocks will either find the static file or follow @rewriterules and try adding .php.

Comment: the folder `users/` works, the file `test.php` works too, but the rewrite to `test` won't work.

Comment: seems like it never executed `location @rewriterules`

Comment: ok, error found, it was my fault i wrote `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriterules =404;` after I removed the `=404` everything was ok. But is it possible to add in last instance a 404?

Comment: That does not make sense - @rewriterules is another location block, so you basically leave the current block and execute another one and try to add .php, and afterwards the .php location block takes over. You can add `try_files` to the .php location block to make sure the php file exists and return a 404 error if it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following block to your configuration to handle static files.

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
  access_log        off;
  expires           30d;
  root /path/to/public/root;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me, but can you please explain me what `access_log` and `expires` do?
Are there additional file types to add? I added `svg` because I used lots of them.

Comment: @MarioFridrichovsky  setting `access_log` to `off` makes sure that the http access logs for these files are not recorded. `expires` sets the HTTP Expires header to 30 days for web browsers to encourage static file caching on user's browser.